# How to get Touch Event TouchUp using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Am trying **to change the screen** when removes his finger/**no longer touches** the screen
Have tried doing it this way

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched(0)) {
camera.unproject(_touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
//stuff...
}
```

Now When ever the User leaves his finger i want to change the Screen 
Have also tried to use this call

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(processor);
```

But of **no idea how to check/use this event in render method**.
Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your class implement `InputProcessor` and call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);`

Answer (score 3):

You can detect [touchUp](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html#touchUp%28com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int%29) events just overriding the proper method from a `Screen` subclass.-

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {         
    boolean res = super.touchUp(x, y, pointer, button);

    // Do your stuff here

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(processor);
```

you don't have to call any function in your render method. Libgdx will directly give you a call back in your processor about the various events. you just need to write the code to change the screen in touch up function of your processor (InputProcessor). use this link to get more clarification https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent

Answer (score 0):

boolean isTouched = Gdx.input.isTouched();

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Gdx.input.justTouched()` instead of `isTouched()`